# Is there a way of calling bind view on a cursor adapter when the data hasn't changed

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview backed by a fairly data heavy cursor adapter that I want to refresh and rebind the views when I change the units the data is displayed in.

So I have temperature in Celsius and via settings screen allow the user to switch to Fahrenheit. At the moment there is a several second delay before the view is redrawn, I want to have it fairly instance when the user hits back from the settings screen.

When Bindview on the cursor adapter is called for each row it gets the data from the cusror and converts depeding on the unit. When the user changes the unit I'd like to redraw the view.

adatper.notifyDatasetChanged doesn't work, i guess because the data hasn't changed.

Any suggestions? or is there a better way of doing it?